# Convert JSON to Parquet

Tags: avro, parquet

I have a few TB logs data in JSON format, I want to convert them into Parquet format to gain better performance in analytics stage.

I've managed to do this by writing a mapreduce java job which uses  [parquet-mr](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/) and [parquet-avro](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/tree/master/parquet-avro).

The only thing I'm not satisfied with is that, my JSON logs doesn't have a fixed schema, I don't know all the fields' names and types. Besides, even I know all the fields' names and types, my schema evolves as time goes on, for example, there will be new fields added in future.

For now I have to provide a Avro schema for `AvroWriteSupport`, and avro only allows fixed number of fields.

Is there a better way to store arbitrary fields in Parquet, just like JSON?

Answer (score 4):

One thing for sure is that Parquet needs a Avro schema in advance. We'll focus on how to get the schema.

1. Use SparkSQL to convert JSON files to Parquet files.

   SparkSQL can infer a schema automatically from data, thus we don't need to provide a schema by ourselves. Every time the data changes, SparkSQL will infer out a different schema.
2. Maintain an Avro schema manually.

   If you don't use Spark but only Hadoop, you need to infer the schema manually. First write a mapreduce job to scan all JSON files and get all fields, after you know all fields you can write an Avro schema. Use this schema to convert JSON files to Parquet files.

   There will be new unknown fields in future, every time there are new fields, add them to the Avro schema. So basically we're doing SparkSQL's job manually.

Comment: I am, amazingly enough, working on very similar problem.  Do you know of any examples of your second option?  I've only worked with Spark and not written Hadoop MapReduce jobs.

Comment: Actually I'm using the second way in production, my schema has over 3000 fields, this schema is inferred out by a MapReduce program, and every time where there are new fields, I need to generate the schema again.

Comment: That's great!  Glad you found it workable.  I also posted another related question if you wanted to share any tips or tricks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35495041/mapreduce-job-to-collect-all-unique-fields-in-hdfs-directory-of-json

Answer (score 1):

Use Apache Drill!

From https://drill.apache.org/docs/parquet-format/, in 1 line of SQL.

After setup Apache Drill (with or without HDFS), execute sqline.sh to run SQL queries:

```
// Set default format ALTER SESSION SET `store.format` = 'parquet'; 
ALTER SYSTEM SET `store.format` = 'parquet';

// Migrate data
CREATE TABLE dfs.tmp.sampleparquet AS  (SELECT trans_id,  cast(`date` AS date) transdate,  cast(`time` AS time) transtime,  cast(amount AS double) amountm, user_info, marketing_info, trans_info  FROM dfs.`/Users/drilluser/sample.json`);
```

Should take a few time, maybe hours, but at the end, you have light and cool parquet files ;-)

In my test, query a parquet file is x4 faster than JSON and ask less ressources.