# Json to Parquet with custom schema with Spark

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, deserialization, parquet

What I'm trying to do is something similar to the Stackoverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33028272/convert-json-to-parquet): basically converting `.seq.gz` **JSON** files to **Parquet** files with a proper schema defined.

**I don't want to infer the schema**, rather I would like to define my own, ideally having my Scala case classes so they can be reused as models by other jobs.

I'm not too sure whether I should deserialise my JSON into a case class and let `toDS()` to implicitly convert my data like below:

```
spark
  .sequenceFile(input, classOf[IntWritable], classOf[Text])
  .mapValues(
    json => deserialize[MyClass](json.toString) // json to case class instance 
  )
  .toDS()
  .write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
  .parquet(outputFile)
```

...or rather use a **Spark Data Frame** schema instead, or even a **Parquet schema**. But I don't know how to do it though.

My objective is having full control over my models and possibly map JSON types (which is a poorer format) to Parquet types.

Thanks!

Comment: Code snippet doesn't match what you are expecting. Maybe a typo somewhere but can you correct it?

Comment: Edited. Thanks @D3V. I hope it's clearer now.